# Get a specific value from a specific column from specific row?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a table names "highscore"

In the table there is:
id (int) ,
name (string) , 
win(int) , 
draw(int), 
loss(int).

I want to make a query that i can get the specific value win from the row , only the integer.. how can i do that? i want to handle sql injection to.

I have a method that update the win, but i need to get the win, increment the value with 1 and then update. My update method is this and it works:

```
    public void updateWin(String playerName, int win) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.KEY_WIN, win);

    db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, values, Constants.KEY_PLAYER_NAME + "= ?", new String[]{playerName});

    db.close();
}
```

Anyone can help me please? thanx

Comment: so you want a query to get value of "win"?

Comment: yes, or do i need the whole object of player then take out the win value ?

Comment: Select win from your_table_name where id = your_id

Comment: i want to use playername to find that value.. show me a code that also take care of sql injection ?

Comment: This is not how Stackoverflow works. You have done nothing from your part. We are not working for you. Learn how to ask help. Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1 - Increment according to arithmetic calculation within SQL

You could base the this on the SQL (assuming the table is **mytable001** and the player's name is **FRED**) :-

```
UPDATE mytable001 SET win = win +1 WHERE playername = 'FRED';
```

This would do away with the need to query the playername to get the current number of wins as it directly increments the value.

However, this cannot be done via the convenience update method nor a rawQuery you have utilise execSQL.

So the following could be used :-

```
public boolean incrementWin(String playerName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String esc_playername = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(playerName);
    String qrysql = "UPDATE " +
            Constants.TABLE_NAME +
            " SET " +
            Constants.KEY_WIN + " = " +
            Constants.KEY_WIN + " + 1" +
            " WHERE " +
            Constants.KEY_PLAYER_NAME + "=" + esc_playername;
    db.execSQL(qrysql);
    long changes = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,"SELECT changes()",null);
    db.close();
    return changes > 0;
}
```

- Note if the update couldn't be/ wasn't performed then it would return false.
- The use of `sqlEscapeString`, will escape the playername and I believe offer some protection against SQL Injection.

### Option 2 - Retrieve current value, calculate new, update using new   :-

```
public boolean incWin(String playername) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = Constants.KEY_PLAYER_NAME + "=?";
    String[] wherargs = new String[]{playername};
    int win = -1; // default to not update

    Cursor csr = db.query(
            Constants.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            whereclause,
            wherargs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        win = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_WIN)) + 1;
    }
    csr.close();
    if (win < 1) {
        db.close();
        return false;
    }
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Constants.KEY_WIN,win);
     if (db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME,cv,whereclause,wherargs) > 0) {
         db.close();
         return true;
     }
     db.close();
     return false;
}
```

- Note if the update couldn't be/ wasn't performed then it would return false.

Comment: Wow thanx! :) That helped me a lot !